# Tax settings for a particular website

Tags: multistore, tax, websites

I wonder if it possible to set a tax rule for a particular website without any dependence on a specific country.

For example: I have 2 websites on my site - for english language and for german language. I want to set the taxes for all the products on english website to 19%, and on german website to 20% - for all the countries at the same time.

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Have a look at this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158123/magento-tax-rates-multiple-countries

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but that answer did not solve my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14159178/2523590

Comment: What happens when you set the tax rule for each website? And are you using websites or storeviews?